# PostgreSQL ON CONFLICT ON

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got problem with my query, because it seems to be ambiguous.
What I need is to insert new row to my table, but if I insert item which has got the same number it should only update quantity.

```
cur.execute(
  """INSERT INTO store VALUES(DEFAULT, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
                ON CONFLICT (number) 
                DO UPDATE SET quantity=quantity+%s""", 
  (
    name, producent, model, number, quantity, 
    warehouse, location, quantity
  )
)
```

Comment: So, what's your problem?

Comment: I'm not a regular PostgreSQL user, but shouldn't you use something like `SET quantity=quantity+EXCLUDED.quantity`? That's shown in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html

Comment: @BillKarwin changed it as you suggested but i received error: 
no unique or exclusive constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification

Comment: Do you have a UNIQUE constraint defined for the `number` column? I guess you don't. The manual is pretty unclear on this, but there must be a UNIQUE constraint on the columns you use to check for conflicts, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The general problem you're trying to solve has the names [“merge” or “upsert”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)#upsert), because you want “update an existing row but insert a new one if there's no existing row” in an atomic operation. You are correct to use [PostgreSQL's `INSERT … ON CONFLICT (…) DO UPDATE …`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) to solve this.

Your specific problem is how to set a field value based on the existing field value, in the case of an update. The PostgreSQL documentation for the `ON CONFLICT` clause addresses this:

> The `SET` and `WHERE` clauses in `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` have access to the existing row using the table's name (or an alias), and to rows proposed for insertion using the special `excluded` table.

So your `SET` clause can address the `excluded` table to get the proposed `quantity` value:

```sql
INSERT INTO store
VALUES (DEFAULT, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
ON CONFLICT (number) DO
UPDATE SET quantity = (store.quantity + excluded.quantity)
```

Comment: I don't think that solves the problem, since the ambiguity must be with the `quantity` immediately after the `=`.

Answer (score 0):

bignose's answer contains the clue to the solution: since `quantity` is a column of both `excluded` and the original table, you have to disambiguate:

```
... DO UPDATE SET quantity = store.quantity + %s
```